# How can I apply PCA on term-document matrix in R?

Tags: r, text-mining, pca

How can I apply PCA on term-document matrix in R?

I've got a document and I've applied PCA on the term-document matrix but all the pc components are zero. I'm wondering if it is a right way to perform PCA analysis.

Comment: Perhaps you need to expand the matrix.  Can you give a small example of what your matrix looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Although this looks like a question that should be posted on CrossValidated you should consider this:

If the matrix consists of rows representing documents describing how many ocurrences of the term exist in it per column, then you should consider using Multiple Correspondence Analysis. PCA assumes you are dealing with continues variables.

Check out this [post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont) on crossvalidated.
Hope this helps.